# Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2 working moments ago but now I cannot access VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I set up Windows Terminal using Ubuntu 20.04 and it was working great. I was able to access Visual Studio Code until I began receiving errors. VSC is my bread-and-butter to coding through WSL2 so can anybody help me with this error? (I have not done any updates to VSC or Ubuntu 20.04. This just happened 30 minutes ago.)

My VSC error is this:

```
/c/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: 61: /c/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe: not found
```

I dug through the location of the `code` file of my computer and went to line 61 of the error of where it is coming from:

```
ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@"
exit $?
```

Would anybody know if anyone has experienced this issue? I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my computer and it seems to be working now. I always put my computer in Sleep so not sure if the system needs to be turned off. Hope this helps anyone out there.